# Are there non-surjective homeomorphisms?

Tags: general-topology

[This document](http://homepage.math.uiowa.edu/~jsimon/COURSES/M132Fall07/M132Fall07_QuotientSpaces.pdf) states (Example 0.6) that the set of all homeomorphisms of a space $X$ **onto itself** forms a group.

I'm confused. Isn't a homeomorphism supposed to be onto anyway? Is there a non-surjective homeomorphism? I'm not trying to point out obvious flaws; I'm only trying to reassess my understanding of the concept.

Comment: By that phrase, they just mean homeomorphisms $X → X$, i.e. whose domain *and codomain* is $X$.

Comment: In other words, only **itself** should be in vold. Or you might ask, why homeomorphims **of a space** ...? Aren't all homeomorphisms defined on a space?

Answer (score 3):

Strictly speaking, it may be seen as a bit of a redundancy. However it is also helps avoid cofusion.  Note that a space can be homeomorphic to a proper subspace: *e.g.*, any infinite discrete space is homoemorphic to all of its subspaces of the same cardinality.  The modifier "*onto itself*" is there to ensure that the collection explicitly excludes such homeomorphisms.

Answer (score 0):

Note that the collection $G$ of all homeomorphisms $X\to X$ is a group under composition. This is because the inverse of a homeomorphism $X\to X$ is also a homeomorphism $X\to X$ and the composition of two homeomorphisms $X\to X$ is again a homeomorphism $X\to X$. More generally, the collection of all automorphisms of an object $X$ in a category $\mathscr C$ is a group.

The collection $H$ of all homeomorphisms $X\to Y$ where $Y\neq X$, however, is *not* a group under composition. Indeed, if $f,g:X\to Y$ are homeomorphisms then the compositions $f\circ g$ and $g\circ f$ are not even defined!